# Type inference of generic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I was trying to make something like this work. The point is that I have some `Interface`, then a `Goo` class that has one generic type that extends said interface.

```
interface Interface { a: string; }
class Goo<T extends Interface> { props: T }
class Foo<T extends Goo<T["props"]>> {}
```

I would like to create a `Foo` class that takes generic type that extends this generic `Goo`. Problem is that `Goo` expects a generic argument, which I tried to use the `T["props"]` for, but the syntax checker is showing error that that type does not satisfy the interface.

Usage of said class would look something like this:

```
class Impl implements Interface { a: string; }
type Boo = Foo<Goo<Impl>>;
```

Comment: What about `class Foo<T extends Goo<Interface>> {}`?

Comment: Yeah that actually work and doesn't narrow the type to the interface in more advanced cases.

Comment: If there are some use cases the suggestion doesn't work for, could you edit your question to include a minimal example?

Comment: The suggested solution from @series0ne works but I'm not sure how can I close this issue since it's just a comment and not an response.

Comment: I added it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do this

`class Foo<T extends Goo<Interface>> {}`